# Test class code coverage issue with trigger

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

[image]

I have written a test class for a trigger which is showing as per the below picture.

Below block(Mark as Red) of code is not covering please suggest me how to cover this block.

Please find my test class code below:

```
@isTest
public class Updateincident_Test {
    static testMethod void UpdateIncidentTest() {    
        BMCServiceDesk__Category__c cat = new BMCServiceDesk__Category__c();
        cat.Name='SAR';
        cat.BMCServiceDesk__AvailableForIncidents__c=true;
        cat.BMCServiceDesk__inactive__c=false;
        insert cat;

        Case cs  = new Case();

        cs.Status = 'open';
        cs.Helpdesk_Case_Resolution__c = 'Test 123';
        cs.Helpdesk_Case_Status__c = 'Closed';
        cs.Incident_Owner__c = 'Naveen';
        cs.Incident_Number__c  = '12345';
        Insert cs;

        BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c inc = new BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c();
        inc.Assigned_Staff__c='005800000045QSjAAM';
        inc.Resolution_Summary__c='resolved';
        inc.Service_Request_Form_Type__c='SAR';
        inc.BMCServiceDesk__incidentDescription__c='FSJ SAR test 123';
        inc.Resource_Type__c='New Contractor';
        inc.Start_Date__c = Date.Today();
        inc.SRF_Location__c='Australia';
        inc.Cases__c = cs.id;
        inc.BMCServiceDesk__FKCategory__c=cat.Id;
        insert inc;
        Update Inc;

    }

    }
```

Trigger Code :

```
trigger Updateincident on BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c (after insert, after update) 
{ 
    Map<ID, Case> parentCases = new Map<ID, Case>(); //Making it a map instead of list for easier lookup
    Set<ID> bmsdID = new Set<ID>();

    for(BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c childObj : Trigger.new) 
    {
        bmsdID.add(childObj.Cases__c);
    }

    parentCases = new Map<Id, Case>([SELECT id,Helpdesk_Case_Status__c,Helpdesk_Case_Resolution__c,
        (SELECT ID,Name, BMCServiceDesk__FKStatus__c,Owner.Name,BMCServiceDesk__Status_ID__c,BMCServiceDesk__incidentResolution__c FROM Incidents__r) FROM Case WHERE ID IN :bmsdID]);

    for(ID caseID : parentCases.keySet())
    {
        for(BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c incidents : parentCases.get(caseID).Incidents__r)
        {
            parentCases.get(caseID).Helpdesk_Case_Resolution__c = incidents.BMCServiceDesk__incidentResolution__c;
            parentCases.get(caseID).Helpdesk_Case_Status__c = incidents.BMCServiceDesk__Status_ID__c;
            parentCases.get(caseID).Incident_Owner__c = incidents.Owner.Name;
            parentCases.get(caseID).Incident_Number__c = incidents.Name;            
        }
    }

    update parentCases.values();
}
```

Comment: can you post your trigger code

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the trigger as text? The image cuts off part of the query (which may be important) and its difficult to copy text from an image into an answer.

Comment: What Santanu said. Specifically, the outer for loop is being completely skipped, which would suggest that your `parentCases` Map is empty. Can't see the full query in the screencap, which seems the likely cause.

Comment: I have added my trigger code , please suggest now.

Comment: I've upvoted this question because OP is continuing to add additional information, the question is clear, and some effort at making the test method has been shown.

Answer (score 3):

Your screenshot doesn't show the critical SOQL filters on `Case` in the query that's being performed, but the code coverage pattern looks pretty clear. The test data that you are inserting in your test class doesn't include any Cases matching the query, so `parentCases.keySet()` is empty and the loop body never executes.

Edit: Having seen your trigger code, it's not immediately clear *why* this is the case. Do you have any other automation on either object? Do you observe any errors? What do `System.debug()` statements tell you about the data you're getting back in your trigger?

I'd really recommend taking some time to read through [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests). Right now, your test is making no assertions about the behavior of your code, and therefore "proves" nothing about whether it is acting correctly or not. This is often called a smoke test, because it shows nothing beyond whether or not the code crashes in a specific situation (and often not even that, if overzealous exception handlers are in place).

Comment: I have added my trigger code , please suggest now

Comment: adding your code doesnt change much,  you should probably check the link posted by @David Reed for writting Good Unit Tests and **[edit]** your post andbBased on your Post History, I would suggest you take a look at [Trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules) since you seem to be lacking the basics...